# Networking in bare metal x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, networking, operating-system, osdev

I began the journey of writing a toy Operating system and I am in the process of finding resources and books to help me.

One feature I haven't been able to figure out is Networking. All tutorials about networking in x86 assembly that I could find are based around Unix/Linux networking syscalls.

How could it be done in bare-metal x86 assembly?

Comment: In bare-metal x86 assembly it's a bit hard because you first need to write a driver for your network card.  See e.g. [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Ne2000) for a description of how to program the simple NE2000 chipset.  Then you have to write your own network stack.  This has been done before but is seriously quite a bit of work.

Comment: @fuz So, do I have to write driver for every single network card that could be used in this OS?

Comment: If the OS doesn't provide any drivers on it's own, that's precisely what you need to do.

Comment: There are two cards commonly used for hobby operating system projects: the Novell NE2000 (including clones) and the Intel E1000 (Pro/1000).  Both are reasonably easy to get and for a hobby project, it's a good idea to restrict yourself to just one or two models.

Comment: @fedqx: Yes, for the same reason the Linux kernel has so many drivers for different NICs.  You said "bare metal", which means no help from firmware to provide a portable / abstract interface to hardware.  (IDK if there even is any UEFI support for network access or anything which you could use from a UEFI application, if you wanted to give up on the idea of fully bare metal with your own drivers like a mainstream OS like *BSD or Linux.)

Comment: @fuz What about onboard Ethernet on motherboards? How could someone write drivers for that? And what would happen in case of closed source drivers?

Comment: @fedqx You need to check what model ethernet controller you have on that mainboard and write a driver for it.  There are open source drivers for all common models and you can often adapt them.  I recommend the drivers shipped with BSD systems as their licenses are less restrictive.

Comment: @fuz Thanks, if you can write all your comments as an answer I can mark this question as answered

Comment: @fedqx Sure.  But please note that writing the pure Ethernet driver is in total a pretty small part of writing a network stack.  Implementing IP and then TCP is a lot more compelx.

Comment: If you are writing your own operating system then by definition you need to write a driver for not only every network card that can be used for this os, but every video card, every usb hub, every usb keyboard, mouse, wifi module, keyboard status leds, and on and on, that is the task of writing an operating system so by definition yes.  every network card you want to support.

Comment: the ne2000 is fine for sims and such but really the best approach is to take the open source drivers (linux, bsd, etc) as well as use linux or other to detect and determine what cards you have in your system (early on you need to create an lspci replacement to if nothing else talk to the pcie controller in the x86 (another massive driver project) to then get the pid/vid out of any card plugged in and so on and so on....

Comment: @old_timer Is that how its done in *nix systems? No wonder why not so many operating systems are on the market

Comment: closed source drivers you need an nda which you wont get.  closed document drivers you use the linux or bsd drivers as a reference.

Comment: there is no market for other operating systems on x86, other platforms sure, but it is really really hard to make something that folks would rather use than linux when that is an option for some platform...it is more of an educational exercise more than anything to write a new one.

Comment: linux isnt great or powerful or fast or whatever its like gcc, it works well enough, better support than anything else, enough people and companies out there to be motivated to port to some new platform, hard to make (sell) a new platform if you dont provide a bsp with some operating system, usually linux.

Comment: @old_timer Thanks! like I said if you can post it as an answer,  I can mark it as question solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for every network card you want to support you need a driver.  For every video card, a driver.  For every keyboard, mouse, USB hub, etc, etc.  But not until you have a driver for the pcie controller, USB root controller, etc.

IMO the bulk of the work for an OS is the drivers.  When you become a Windows or a Linux then the vendors want to write the drivers for your OS and all you have to do is approve them or not, but long before that happens you have to write them without much access to documentation.  Very often the Linux driver source is all you have to figuring out how to talk to the device.

Video historically has been closed document, network didn't start off that way but Broadcom and Realtek are basically closed document, and even if you were a very large corporation you likely couldn't get an NDA, and if you had an NDA you would have to be very careful as to what you did with it, posting source to drivers based on it on GitHub is a good way to lose your house in a lawsuit (create an LLC before you get into any of these deals to protect your personal assets, and get a lawyer).  So again, take the Linux sources, be mindful of the licenses being used for that source code...

Not sure what your goals are but I would do x86 last or never, start on some ARM be it a big cortex-m7 mcu or a full sized arm, Raspberry Pi, beagle something (the beagles use ti parts which are open document), espresso/macchiatobin, etc. The Pi has a second to none, even better than the avr freaks back in the day, bare metal forum despite being Broadcom with minimal documentation. A uart as your primary interface, just getting task switching and starting to form ideas about driver interfaces and application space vs kernel and having applications run will entertain you for a long time.

If you want x86, that's fine; you must be into some special kind of pain.  I would rather get a tattoo on the bottom of my foot, it hurts less and heals faster.

And you tagged this assembly, I hope you are not writing this in assembly, but if you are I hope you understand it won't execute faster than writing it in C and compiling it.  You can very often hand tune compiled code, it isn't nor will ever be "perfect", but for a large project the compiler is going to be more consistent.  And when you get tired of processor X most of your code should port to processor Y and you can keep going. Your experience will vary.

The fact based on the question(s) you are asking implies you might not see the size of the project, the time it will take.  Maybe you do and you are into that.  Also understand you will not hit a home run the first time at bat, expect to hack and slash it apart or toss it and start over from scratch a number of times.  Write lots of throwaway code to get something working and then actually throw it away after you create the real code.

Any one thing, be it one keyboard, the phy on one network board, etc can be itself a research project taking weeks of full time work.  Be prepared for what you are getting into.

It is very doable, individuals have done this without other programmers, these operating systems are out there if you look, just want you to see the big picture, then add to that the lack of support from the vendors that make the products you want to use.

---

> One feature I haven't been able to figure out is Networking. All tutorials about networking in x86 assembly that I could find are based around Unix/Linux networking syscalls.

Syscalls are not the interesting part of the problem.  The network cards are mostly closed book so you need the Linux sources to have a chance.  Networking itself is very well documented, but you want to start with the oldest RFCs first, was on Wikipedia the other day and seems like they have links to them, which is good.  For example ICMP (you need arp/rarp first) Wikipedia appears to have done a really good job on this one over and above what you will need to get ping to work.  but you see RFC 792 at the bottom, then in that you see RFC 777 and 760 and 700 and such, I found it best when trying to do my own stack, to start with the older ones, as the newest ones either have holes or are written in a way that you are expected to have been in the business and looking at these for decades.  The older ones are simpler and easier to understand and get started.

There are a few networking books.  The Comer books which I couldn't afford when I was interested in this stuff, and then TCP/IP illustrated series which I was sent free copies (can probably get illegal PDFs these days).  The OSI layer which you can find at Wikipedia as well and the Andrew S. Tanenbaum books are out there that are used to teach this.

But at the end of the day one half of it is the hardware which gives you packets of data.  The other half is the protocols which are the contents/payloads in those packets.

> How could it be done in bare-metal x86 assembly?

An operating system is essentially a bare-metal program so that covers bare metal.  The programming language is the programming language C is by far best for this work there is no close second.  But asm you just write the code, the  algorithm/task you are performing and the code it takes to perform it are two different things.  If you know the task/algorithm/procedure then you just bang out the code, come back later and clean it up...

99% of baremetal is reading or let's say not writing the final code, some of that 99% is throwaway code it takes to figure out how the thing really works because almost all documents have bugs even well written but most are poorly written.

The writing of the code in whatever language is the easy part.

> @fuz So, do I have to write driver for every single network card that could be used in this OS?

Yes, absolutely...That is what making an OS is all about.  Fortunately there are fewer chips than vendors and a good percentage are just buying the same chips making the board and putting their name on it.  So many pcie vendor/product ids may map to the same driver.